# How to keep Toastr Notification alive after redirection to another page in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, toastr

I am developping an ASP MVC 5 application and I am heading up a problem with the showing of a Toast's Notifaction.

The toast notifaction appears after updating the informations of a user in order to confirm the success of operation.

Unfortunately it disappears quickly (in 2 seconds) after the loading of the next page. I think this is due to the using of server side code (C# in this case), where the entire page reloads, including the javascript files. This is why the toastr disappears too.

Is there any way to keep it a lil longer ?

I tried to o pass the necessary information to the next page, so that page two would know to display the toastr instead of page1 but it didn't work.

This is the code's snippet :

**View :**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Client", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Update()">
    }

        <script src="/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/toastr.js"></script>
        <script>

            function Update() {
                toastr.success("Your infos are updated with succes !");
            }
        </script>
```

**Controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Client cmodel)
    {
        try
        {

                ClientManagement cdb = new ClientManagement();
            if (cdb.UpdateDetails(cmodel))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Client Details Edited Successfully";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Profil");
        }
        catch
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
```

**Profil :**

```
 public ActionResult Profil()
    {
        ClientManagement dbhandle = new ClientManagement();
        ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
        return View(dbhandle.GetClientsInfo());
    }
```

In View Profil (buttom of page) :

```
 <link href="~/Content/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
script src="~/scripts/toastr.js"></script>
        <script src="~/scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>

     @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("@ViewBag.Message");</script>
    }
```

Comment: Why not use Ajax?

Comment: I tried with the ajax also but the same problem persist

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass ***one-time message*** from an action method to another action method, you will need to use ***TempData***.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Client cmodel)
{
   try
   {
      ClientManagement cdb = new ClientManagement();
      if (cdb.UpdateDetails(cmodel))
      {
         TempData["Message"] = "Client Details Edited Successfully";
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Profil");
   }
   catch
   {
      return View(cmodel);
   }
}
```

You then retrieve it at the next page either inside action method or view. Please note that it would be cleared out at the end of the request after you read it.

**Profil.cshtml**

```
@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
   <script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("@TempData["Message"]");</script>
}
```

### Update

[image]

Above code works. If you use default ASP.NET MVC Layout, please make sure you place the script inside ***Scripts*** section, so that it renders after jQuery.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @if (TempData["Message"] != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("@TempData["Message"]");</script>
    }
}
```

*FYI: If you use toastr in other places, you might want to consider bundle and minfy them with other scripts and styles.*

Comment: thx for the answer, but it didn't work ! I think coz the position of the script in my View is wrong, anyway I will update my question to show what I did

Comment: I tried what you suggest but this time the toast didn't work at all, I don't know what is the reason

Comment: Before working on redirect, please make sure `toastr` works in `Profil.cshml` with hard-coded text `<script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("Hello!");</script>`. If not, could you create a new question with the rendered source inside browser? I'm happy to take a look at it.

Comment: When I added this hard-coded text inside the section scripts which you had sent to me, it didn't work

Comment: I'm 100% confident that ASP.NET MVC is working, because I tested the above code, but `toastr` has an issue at your side - it cannot even display hard-coded text message. So, please create a new question with the rendered source inside browser. I'm happy to take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160207/discussion-between-exact-and-win).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576977/rendered-source-inside-browser-failed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to redirect to "Profil", then I agree you could use Ajax and on the `success` callback you could show your toastr. If you need to redirect then you can set the `ViewBag.Message` as you do and then do something like

```
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
<script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("@ViewBag.Message");</script>
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but can you please specify more why ? because you gived me another suggestion that can not also still appearing

Comment: Do you get an error in the console (like toastr is not defined)?

Comment: Might be a silly question but is there any chance that `ViewBag.Message`  is null, so the code that displays the toastr is never hit?

Comment: I don't think so, the problem is due to Jquery error in my profile view, please  take a look at this question if you want : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576977/rendered-source-inside-browser-failed?noredirect=1#comment82111916_47576977