# Rendered source inside browser failed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, toast

Using ASP MVC and JQuery, I am trying to show a Toast Notifaction but I got a problem with showing the rendred source inside the browser.

I used this hard coded text as example but I didn't get any notifaction:

```
    <script src="/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/scripts/toastr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

   <script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("Hello!");</script>
}
```

Comment: You do not need both `toastr.js` and `toastr.min.js`; `toastr.min.js` is enough. Do you see any script error inside console? Could you show the rendered source inside browser?

Comment: yes i delete one and I got this error inside the browser :
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:60585/(S(gkiezxvswsx2uqia5x0d2tdm))/Client/Profil:268:34)
    at i (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27151)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27914)
    at Function.ready (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:29707)
    at HTMLDocument.J (http://localhost:60585/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:29892)

Comment: You are using jQuery UI. Please make sure you include jQuery UI script after jQuery.

Comment: I doubt about it also but I find it like : 
<script src="/template/web/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/template/web/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Could you place those script tags inside `<head>` tag and try again?

Comment: So, I fixed most of bugs, still only this one : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at http://localhost:60585/(S(aeq53dcwkiwentydgu1ryzrb))/Client/Profil:266:13

Comment: Could you place those script tags inside <head> tag and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using `jQuery UI` component `datepicker`, before `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` script are being rendered. As the result, it causes the script error, and `toastr` ends up not working.

So, you will need to move those `jQuery`, `jQuery UI` and `toastr` scripts inside ***head*** tag.

Comment: The errors disappear now but the problem of toast still occur

Comment: There is no error but the toast notifaction disappear with the loading of the profil page

Comment: Does this solve [the original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47574400/296861) or do you still have the issue?

Comment: Can you see toastr with hard-coded text? `<script type="text/javascript">toastr.success("Hello!");</script>` If not, do you see any script error in console?